# Fruit Shooter game trying to end

Tags: java, arrays

Im trying to make this game just like bubble shooter,
I'm trying quit the game when all fruits are removed but i could't figured it out how?!
I sorted my fruits in arrays but couldn't find how i know when all fruits are removed!!
THanks please help!!

```
    for (int k = 0; k < fruits.length; k++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < fruits[k].length; j++) {
            if (fruits[k][j] == null || fruits[19][19] == null) {                   

                continue;   

            }

            if (fruits[k][j].getLocationX() > fruits[19][19].getLocationX() + fruits[19][19].getWidth()
                    || fruits[k][j].getLocationX() + fruits[k][j].getWidth() < fruits[19][19].getLocationX()
                    || fruits[k][j].getLocationY() > fruits[19][19].getLocationY() + fruits[19][19].getWidth()
                    || fruits[k][j].getLocationY() + fruits[k][j].getWidth() < fruits[19][19].getLocationY()) {
                // No colloision
                continue;
            }

            // Not counting each other
            if (!(k == 19 && j == 19)) {
                // Törmäys
                fruits[19][19].setSpeedX(0);
                fruits[19][19].setSpeedY(0);

                // collision same fruits

                if (fruits[k][j].getImage() == fruits[19][19].getImage()) {

                    removeFruits(k, j, fruits[19][19].getImage());
                    collision = true;

                    removeSeparate();

                }
                else if(isInBounds(k + 1, j) && fruits[k + 1][j] != null && fruits[k + 1][j].getImage() == fruits[19][19].getImage()){
                    removeFruits(k + 1, j, fruits[19][19].getImage());
                    collision = true;
                    removeSeparate();

                }
                else if(isInBounds(k - 1, j) && fruits[k - 1][j] != null && fruits[k - 1][j].getImage() == fruits[19][19].getImage()){
                    removeFruits(k - 1, j, fruits[19][19].getImage());
                    collision = true;
                    removeSeparate();
                }
                //                  // adding the fruits
                else {
                    collisionX = k;
                    collisionY = j;
                }

            }

        }
    }

    if (collision) {
        fruits[19][19] = null;

    }


    else if (collisionX != -1 && collisionY != -1) {

        fruits[collisionX][collisionY + 1] = fruits[19][19];
        fruits[19][19] = null;

        fruits[collisionX][collisionY + 1].setPosX(collisionX);
        fruits[collisionX][collisionY + 1].setPosY(collisionY + 1);
        fruits[collisionX][collisionY + 1].setLocationX(fruits[collisionX][collisionY].getLocationX());
        fruits[collisionX][collisionY + 1].setLocationY(fruits[collisionX][collisionY].getLocationY()+fruits[collisionX][collisionY].getWidth());
    }

    if (fruits[19][19] != null && fruits[19][19].getLocationY() < 0) {
        int x = fruits[19][19].getLocationX() / fruits[19][19].getWidth();
        fruits[19][19].setLocationY(0);
        fruits[19][19].setLocationX(x * fruits[19][19].getWidth());
        fruits[19][19].setWidth(50);
        fruits[19][19].setSpeedX(0);
        fruits[19][19].setSpeedY(0);
        fruits[x][0] = fruits[19][19];
        fruits[x][0].setPosX(x);
        fruits[x][0].setPosY(0);
        fruits[19][19] = null;

        if (isInBounds(x - 1 , 0) && fruits[x - 1][0] != null && fruits[x - 1][0].getImage() == fruits[x][0].getImage()) {
            removeFruits(x - 1, 0, fruits[x][0].getImage());

        }
        if (isInBounds(x + 1 , 0) &&  fruits[x + 1][0] != null && fruits[x + 1][0].getImage() == fruits[x][0].getImage()) {
            removeFruits(x + 1, 0, fruits[x][0].getImage());

        }

    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

The code is confusing, so I'm not completely sure of what you are actually doing. I'm going to assume that the array `fruits` contains instances of `Fruit`. Given that, I see two possibilities:

1. If you remove the fruits from the array `fruits`, you can just check when the array is empty
2. If you don't remove the fruits from the array `fruits`, I would have a counter of the fruits left that you decrease every time you remove one.

I can probably give you a better answer if you provide me the code of `removeFruit` and more infomation on the data structure being used.

EDIT:
Yes, if you are removing fruits in that way, you have to go with option 2. Just keep a counter of fruits left and decrease it everytime.